# Django auto deployment using Fabric

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, fabric

I wanted to automatically deploy my django project by using Fabric3

Here is my fabfile.py

```
    from fabric.api import env
    from fabric.api import run
    from fabric.operations import sudo

    GIT_REPO = "https://github.com/........"

    env.user = 'root'
    env.password = '...'

    env.hosts = ['demo....com']
    env.port = '22'


    def deploy():
        source_folder = '/home/.../sites/..../...'

        run('cd %s && git pull' % source_folder)
        run("""
            cd {} &&
            ../env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt &&
            ../env/bin/python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
            ../env/bin/python3 manage.py migrate
            """.format(source_folder))
        sudo('restart gunicorn-demo.charon.me')
        sudo('service nginx reload')
```

And here is how I run it:

`python fabfile.py fab deploy`

And finally here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/charon/Documents/PycharmProjects/try_blog/fabfile.py", line 1, in 
    from fabric.api import env
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/api.py", line 10, in 
    from fabric.context_managers import (cd, hide, settings, show, path, prefix,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/context_managers.py", line 27, in 
    from fabric.state import output, win32, connections, env
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/state.py", line 9, in 
    from fabric.network import HostConnectionCache, ssh
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 16, in 
    from fabric.exceptions import NetworkError
ImportError: cannot import name 'NetworkError'
```

Plz help me with this!!!!

Comment: Looks like your installation is broken. Try desinstalling / reinstalling fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `fab -f fabfile.py deploy`

Anyway, you probably have a messed up install, try:

```
which python
```

Does that match:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

fabric has two versions. Your code mismatch the version of fabric.

```
pip uninstall fabric

pip install 'fabric<2.0'
```

then things will be all right.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by just writing the below command might work in the working directory:

```
fab deploy
```

**NOT** :

```
python fabfile.py fab deploy
```